# reading multiple lines as input in scala

Tags: scala

I have a number of lines as input and want to read and print the exact same thing. The problem is I don't know how! (`readLine`)
The input comes from a user typing in terminal.

the first integer is the number of lines in total!

input:

```
4
word
localization
internationalization
```

output:

```
word
localization
internationalization
```

Comment: the input comes from a user typing into a terminal. Beacuse readLine gets the input

Comment: `readLine` does read a line from stdin. What didn't work about it?

Comment: I want the program to read multiple lines simultaneously! readLine reads one line only

Comment: 2 options: call `readLine` several times, or write your own utility based on `InputStream`

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
// default condition: string is not empty, not inclusive! 
class TermLines (cond: (String => Boolean) = _ != "") extends Iterator[String] { 
  var s = readLine; 
  def hasNext = cond(s); 
  def next = { var r = s; s = readLine; r } 
}
```

Then call it like

```
println((new TermLines).toVector.mkString("\n")) // till empty
```

or

```
println(new TermLines(_ != ".").toVector.mkString("\n")) // till last is dot
```

Comment: this is beautiful

Answer (score -1):

Solved!

```
import scala.io.StdIn

object Solution extends App
{
    val numOfLines = StdIn.readInt()
    def words: Seq[String] = for (_ <- 1 to numOfLines) yield StdIn.readLine()
    def sort = words.map
    {
        case word => word
    }
    sort.foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: The `.map()` call doesn't do anything so `sort` is _exactly_ the same as `words`.

Comment: That's not the whole code. I cut the code.  case word if word.length > 10 =>  (s"${word.head}${(word.length - 2).toString}${word.last}") 
        case word => word. But you are RIGHT!

Comment: Two sets of parens `()` are unneeded and the `.toString` is unneeded. The use of `readInt()` is dangerous. Glad it works for you but it's not a very good solution for the actual question as posted.